# What causes the Ckan 2.8 DataStore Not Authorized error?

Tags: ckan

I get error NotAuthorized when I upload file to DataStore. Anyone have any thoughts on the problem?

```
Error: File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/__init__.py", line 306, in check_access raise NotAuthorized(msg) NotAuthorized('',)
```

This problem does not apply to all dataset. Sometimes I get errors like this.

Ckan version 2.8

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to dataset's status. If the dataset is private it require authorized users to perform actions.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your reply.
Dataset is public but I can't upload to DataStore with admin account.

I tried submit with cli but got an error again.
`paster --plugin=ckan datapusher submit <pkgname> -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini`